# Passing events between JS sibling classes

Tags: javascript

For a lot of my JS classes, I call a basic modal that covers my page with a white background. Recently I've tried to reduct some of my code and I've put the modal into its own class. The problem I've run into is when I call the modal class from a sibling class the modal variables aren't registered. I've talked to some people and they recommend me looking into Polymorphism but from what I've read it seems to pertain to parent/child class relationships (use of extend). I was curious if there is an easy way with vanilla JS to communicate sibling to sibling with classes? I apologize if this has been touched on a lot but i've been looking around and can't find what I need.

```
class Modal {
  constructor(modal){
    this.modal = modal;
    this.closeButton = modal.querySelector('.modal-close-button');
  }

  activate() {
    this.modal.setAttribute('data-state', 'active');
    document.body.setAttribute('data-state', 'inactive');
  }

  deactivate() {
    this.modal.setAttribute('data-state', 'inactive');
    document.body.setAttribute('data-state', 'active');
  }
}

class Form {
  constructor(button, modal) {
    this.button = button;
    this.formId = button.getAttribute('data-form');
    this.modal = modal;
    this.setEvents();
  }

  setEvents() {
    this.button.addEventListener('click', this.modal.activate);
  }
}
```

Comment: your problem is with what `this` is in an event handler

Comment: you'll need to fix `Form#setEvents` and any handlers in `Modal` accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your help Jaromanda X, I figured this was the case I usually use this.function.bind(this) when handling this issue in the same class but I'm unsure how to set (this) to be in a relationship with my Modal. Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: I've added an answer - you don't actually need to change `setEvents` at all :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest fix is to bind `this.activate` to `this` in the `constructor`

```
class Modal {
  constructor(modal){
    this.modal = modal;
    this.closeButton = modal.querySelector('.modal-close-button');
    // add these two lines
    this.activate = this.activate.bind(this);
    this.deactivate = this.deactivate.bind(this);
  }

  activate() {
    this.modal.setAttribute('data-state', 'active');
    document.body.setAttribute('data-state', 'inactive');
  }

  deactivate() {
    this.modal.setAttribute('data-state', 'inactive');
    document.body.setAttribute('data-state', 'active');
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can change the Form class

```
class Form {
  constructor(button, modal) {
    this.button = button;
    this.formId = button.getAttribute('data-form');
    this.modal = modal;
    this.setEvents();
  }

  setEvents() {
    this.button.addEventListener('click', e => this.modal.activate(e));
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you, this seemed to do the trick. So basically if I want to call a class method from another class I'll have to add the method in the constructor with a .bind(this);

Comment: No. It's to do with event handlers

Comment: I like @JaromandaX's answer better, but you also have the option of: `this.button.addEventListener('click', () => this.modal.activate());`

Comment: Yes. I originally was going to suggest that